# I saw this window at a recycled window outlet, but it was sold and I am trying to find who made it. Any suggestions from these pictures?

Tags: wood, windows, aluminum, green

Who makes this window?  Any ideas.  I saw this at a recycled window outlet, but it was sold.  Aluminum clad in green.

[image: Who makes this window?]

Comment: What does the letters in bold type say on the upper sticker?

Comment: Is that sticker stuck to this window or the one behind it?

Comment: I'm this close to voting to close, as this question is nearly unanswerable. If you want that window, take the picture to your local window vendor and see what they can come up with.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I'm with you, but I don't see your VtC...

Comment: @FreeMan  - I should have used italics on "I'm this close"... I wanted to give the question a chance, on the possibility that some window savant would be like, "oh, that's a marvin blah-blah-blah"

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I agree.I try to give them a little breathing room. After all, we are trying to help them out.

Comment: I agree. (Missed seeing the first 3 words...). I don't see how we'll be able to answer this one, but, who knows. For all we know, it was custom built by some local glazier 80 years ago...

Comment: @FreeMan  ...and that local glazier might be a member of this site... :-)